# OAuth2: works only via Wifi or cellular, not over Bluetooth

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

I managed to run Tizen's own OAuth2 manager, and I can request *access_tokens* perfectly on emulator (Tizen5.5):

```
oauth2_manager_request_access_token(mgr, request, cb, NULL);
```

Code works perfectly on the physical wearable device too, but it has a drawback:

Only works if the wearable device has its own network connection (either via Wifi, or via Cellular module). If it "tethers" via the phone over Bluetooth, OAuth2 can't work.

I think I shall use the proxy feature of `curl`: https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/connectivity/curl/

I have two questions:

1. How is it possible to make Tizen's OAuth2 manager recognize the proxy settings?
2. How can I make the emulator dropping the network connection and simulate the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Tizen wearable device connects with the phone using SPP(Serial Port Profile) profile.
It is connected via BT link and transfer the data. So there is no network interface to use 'data network'.
Wifi and Cellular case, it establish the own network connection and enable to use 'network interface'.
So Bluetooth is different with Wifi and Cellualr.

If Tizen wearable supports 'BT tethering' and connected with phone via BT tethering, then it creates the 'pan0' interface.
So works with Wifi and Celluar samely.
But, Tizen wearable does not support 'BT tethering' and can't connect using tethering.
As I said, only connected using SPP profile.

At result, the physical link and the connected method is totally different from wifi and cellular.
So we can answer that that functionality is not supported on Tizen wearable.

Thanks

Comment: When it connects on Bt, you have to request a proxy address from connection manager. With that proxy address, tizen can reach internet just as it would do with its own (via wifi or lte)